# Scaling of categorical variable

Tags: python, pandas, normalization

1. Does categorical variables needs to scaled before model building?
   I have scaled all my continuous numerical variables using StandardScalear
   now all the continues variables are between -1 and 1 where as categorical columns are binary.
2. How will it it affect my model?
3. Can someone please explain, how a scaled categorical variable will effect the splitting of nodes in the DecisionTreeClassifier

Comment: It depends on what encoding you are using for you categorical variables and also on what decision tree implementation you are using e.g. https://roamanalytics.com/2016/10/28/are-categorical-variables-getting-lost-in-your-random-forests/. Also, there is no need to scale your continuous variables for tree based models.

Comment: Thank you @Dan, This is really helpful

Answer (score 2):

When you one-hot encode your categorical variables, the values in encoded variables become 0 and 1. Therefore, encoded variables will not negatively affect your model. The fact that you encode variables and pass them to ML learning algorithms is good, as you may gain additional insights from ML models.

When scaling your dataset, make sure you pay attention to 2 things:

1. Some ML algorithms require data to be scaled, and some do not. It is a good practice to only scale your data for models that are sensitive to un-scaled data, such as kNN.
2. There are different methods to scale your data. StandardScaler() is one of them, but it is vulnerable to outliers. Therefore, make sure you are using the scaling method that best fits your business needs. You can learn more about different scaling methods here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/preprocessing/plot_all_scaling.html

Encoded categorical variables contain values on 0 and 1. Therefore, there is even no need to scale them. However, scaling methods will be applied to them when you choose to scale your entire dataset prior to using your data with scale-sensitive ML models.

Comment: What is the point of scaling one hot encoded variables? Also, one hot encoding higher cardinality categoricals is not a good idea, especially with trees.

Comment: There is no point scaling encoded variables. What I was trying to say is that it is best practice to first finish treating your dataset with techniques such as feature engineering and encoding, and then once the data is ready for ML algorithms, it is best to scale for algorithms that require scaled dataset.

Comment: Thank you @Arsik36, Your answer is really helpful

Comment: _"Encoded categorical variables in your dataset will not change a way DecisionTreeClassifier() splits the nodes."_ this is not at all true, see the link I posted on the OP

Comment: Thank you for this note. I edited my response and will read your article and learn more from it. I noticed it is 5 years old. Are you confident information there is still relevant today?